# Running tshark in perl script

Tags: perl, tshark

I am trying to run tshark in a perl script, simply by doing the following -

```
my $filter = "port 68 or 67";
my $capture = "tshark -i eth0 -f $filter -a duration:120 -w pcapture.pcap&";
system($capture);
```

This code is not starting the tshark process. Any changes recommended?

Comment: what error code do you get from `system`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `port 68 or 67` is a legal value for `-f`, you need quotes to treat it as one entity (a value which contains whitespace):

```
my $filter = "port 68 or 67";
my $capture = "tshark -i eth0 -f '$filter' -a duration:120 -w pcapture.pcap&";
system($capture);
```